# How to define mongoose query type typescript?

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I build handler factory `mongoose` with typescript.

```
export const getOne = <T extends Document>(Model: Model<T>, popOptions?: string): RequestHandler =>
  catchAsync(async (req: Request<{id: ID}>, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const query: any = Model.findById(req.params.id) 
    if (popOptions) query: errorHere = query.populate(popOptions);
    
    const doc = await query.exec() as DocType<T> | null;

    res.status(200).json({
      status: 'success',
      data: {
        data: doc
      }
    });
  });
```

Here how to add mongoose query type ?

Initially I do `PopulatedDoc<Model>` but also show error